# SQL Query IF equal 2 or 3

Tags: t-sql

What is the best way to write a query where I am asking to return any values in ReveiewType of 2 and 3 with the same ElementID in the dateset below:

```
ReviewType  fiscalYear  ElementID   Cycle   dateCompleted   sNumber
  2            1819         SI-063  2016    2018-09-24       128221
  3            1819         SI-063  2016    2018-09-24       128221
  2            1819         SI-065  2016    2018-09-24       128221
  3            1819         SI-065  2016    2018-09-24       128221
  2            1819         SI-066  2016    2018-09-25       128221
  3            1819         SI-066  2016    2018-09-25       128221
```

This is what I have so far.. what is not working out...

```
  SELECT Distinct ElementID


                    WHERE ElementID Like '#element#'

                    AND ReviewType IN ('2','3')

                    ORDER BY ElementID
 FROM [DATABSE]
```

Comment: Welcome, SALSQL. Just a couple of things. If  `ReviewType` is of type `INT`, then the quotes around the numbers are not necessary. Also, if you want to use wildcards in the `LIKE` statement (which seems to be the case), you should be using `%` instead of `#`.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like homework.  If so, it's polite to let us know.

Instead of `distinct` elementid, I think you'll want to use `group by` elementid with a `having` count(*) > 1 clause.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question but your sql syntax is incorrect.

It should be like this:

```
SELECT 
Distinct ElementID
FROM [DATABSE]
WHERE ElementID Like '%St%'
AND ReviewType IN ('2','3')
ORDER BY ElementID
```

Please elaborate more on what outcome / output do you want from the list of data.